# Magento 2 not see a new theme

Tags: magento2, theme, frontend

I'm trying to create a theme for Magento2 installed with composer.
I created the theme of Vendor, registration.php created the file, the view.xml, the composer as well as attached files.
I checked several times the correctness of the data, set the developer mode, disable the cache and rerun the deploy static content, but **i do not see the theme from select in backend**.

[image]

**`Where am I wrong?`**

Comment: Can you put full path of new created theme ?

Answer (score 1):

Create your theme on below path given instead of vendor folder

```
app\design\frontend\Themes\themename
```

Comment: Create your theme on below path and clear cache. app\design\frontend\